# Nginx how to check if value is false

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Now I'm doing a redirect with this code:

```
if ($args ~* "(utm_|gclid|fbclid)") {
 rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri? permanent;
}
```

and it will redirect if these parameters are added. But how can I do the opposite? In order not to redirect with these parameters, but the condition was false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if), you can use a negative operator: `!~*`

Comment: I think the answer is correct thanks, but now if I do not pass any parameters at all, an endless redirect occurs, can you please tell me the solution?

Comment: @SdafsFasafs what are you trying to accomplish? Redirecting to the same URI, on absence of query parameters, will give you an endless loop, as you noticed yourself.